# Batch file: copy user data

Tags: windows, batch-file

I am trying to write a batch file that will copy certain data from each users directory. But the usernames won't always be the same.

I will need something like:

xcopy "C:\Users\%SOMEUSER%\Documents*" "C:\Migration\%SOMEUSER%\Documents*"

Anyone have any ideas? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for /f %%i in ('dir /b /ad-h c:\users') do xcopy "c:\users\%%i\Documents*" "C:\Migration\%%i\Documents*"
```

Comment: This isn't what I need. I need to run the file, and for it to get certain data from EACH users directory.